# Simultaneously skewsymmetrizing matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ and $B$ be two diagonalizable matrices with purely imaginary eigenvalues. Can one find a nonsingular matrix $U$ such that both $U^{-1}AU$ and $U^{-1}BU$ are skew symmetric?